# Large background images causing lag while scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, scroll

The website I am building has 4 large background images that take up the entire height and width of the user's browser. They are implemented as CSS background divs. The problem is, when scrolling on larger screen sizes, it is very laggy and choppy. Scrolling between these images is done automatically via JavaScript when the user presses a button, so this is part of the core functionality of my website and I must find a way to prevent lag.

So far, I have tried preloading the images via JS and converting the images from PNG to JPEG (increase compression and decrease quality) server-side. Neither of these worked.

The minimum height of the image can be 630 pixels. How can I prevent lag while scrolling between sections?

Here's my code:

CSS:

```
 body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; font-family: HelveticaNeue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }

 .area { height: 630px; border: 0px solid red; background: repeat-x; margin-bottom: 0px; }

 a { text-decoration: none; }
 h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { font-family: Av, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #292E37; font-weight: lighter; }

 #top { position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 10%; background: #292E37; box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 5px #000; z-index: 1000; }
 #navigation { float: right; height: 100%; }
 #bottom { width: 100%; position: fixed; bottom: 0px; padding: 10px; background: #292E37; box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 5px #000; text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #000; color: #fff; }
 #sceneSelection { top: 20%; position: fixed; padding: 10px; }
 #info { margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom: 50px; }
 .box { margin-top: 50px; padding: 75px; background: #292E37; box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 5px #000; text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #000; color: #fff; }

 .nav { position: relative; top: 38%; height: 100%; margin-right: 35px; display: inline-block;  color: #fff; text-shadow: 0px 1px #000; }
 .nav:hover { color: #EA5555; }

 .nimage { float: left; width: 16px; height: 16px; position: relative; top: 5%; left: -20%; }
 .home { background: url(site_images/icons/nav/home.png); }
 .pricing { background: url(site_images/icons/nav/pricing.png); }
 .features { background: url(site_images/icons/nav/features.png); }
 .blog { background: url(site_images/icons/nav/blog.png); }
 .contact { background: url(site_images/icons/nav/contact.png); }
 .about { background: url(site_images/icons/nav/us.png); }

 .logo { font-size: 2em; text-shadow: 0px 1px #000; padding-top: 10px;  padding-left: 15px; color: #EA5555; font-family: Av, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }
 .red { color: #EA5555; }
 .white { color: #fff; text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #000; font-weight: bold; }
 .dark { color: #202020; }

 .center { text-align: center; }
 .left { text-align: left; }
 .right { text-align: right; }

 .larger { font-size: 1.25em; }


 .buttoni { -webkit-border-radius: 2px; -moz-border-radius: 0px; border-radius: 4px; background: #ddd; display: block; color: #ccc; font-size: 14pt; height: 50px; text-align: right; margin: 10px; cursor: pointer; color: #505050; }
 .buttoni:hover { background: #EA5555; color: #fff; }

 .btext { padding: 15px; position: relative; top: 25%; }

 .groundi { background: url(ground_button.png); }
 .skyi { background: url(sky_button.png); }
 .stratospherei { background: url(stratosphere_button.png); }
 .spacei { background: url(space_button.png); }

 .image { height: 50px; width: 50px; float: left; border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; }

 li { color: #EA5555; }
 li span { color: #505050; }
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="space area" id="a4">

  </div>
  <div class="stratosphere area" id="a3">

  </div>
  <div class="sky area" id="a2">

  </div>
  <div class="ground area" id="a1">

  </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function scroll_to(id, speed, margin) {
         $('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: $('#' + id).offset().top - margin
         }, speed);
       }

function match_height() {
         var heights = [11, 630, 693, 756, 819, 882, 945, 1008, 1071, 1134, 1197, 1260, 1323, 1386, 1449, 1512, 1575, 1638, 1701, 1764, 1827, 1890, 1953, 2016, 2079, 2142, 2205, 2268, 2331, 2394, 2457, 2520];

           var browsery = $(window).height();


           var i = 0;

           while(browsery > heights[i]) {
             i++;
           }

           var h = heights[i];

           $(".area").css("height", h + "px");
           $(".area").css("width", "100%");

           $(".ground").css("background", "url(scenes/ground/" + h + ".png)");

           $(".sky").css("background", "url(scenes/sky/" + h + ".png)");
           $(".stratosphere").css("background", "url(scenes/stratosphere/" + h + ".png)");

           $(".space").css("background", "url(scenes/space/" + h + ".png)");


       }

       match_height();

       var pos = 0;

       $(".buttoni").click(function() {
         var id = $(this).attr("id");

         if(pos != id) {
           scroll_to("a" + id, 2000, 0);
         }

         pos = id;
       });
```

Comment: Please make a reduced test case on jsfiddle. The lag could be caused by the js. Have you tried using background-color on the divs to see if the lag persists?

Comment: laggy is also a matter of screen refresh rate, the animation or scroll event your using may be going to fast.

Comment: Hm, I don't see that you're using jquery Animate. and is scroll_to a function that you've defined?

Comment: @AndrewWalters I forgot to include that function. The code has been updated. It uses `$.animate()`.

Comment: I really think that this would benefit from a reduced-case test fiddle. I'd suspect that this problem has something to do with the Javascript, and would benefit from relying more on CSS than JS, but without a test case that's pure conjecture at this point.

Comment: can you at least post the images you're using  to an image hosting site? so that we can use those images while we test your code.. if you don't want to jsfiddle it?

Comment: If you say it's better with a solid background colour, have you tried using a color value with transparency (like #00FFFFFF or rgba(255,255,255,0))?

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle (or similar) link ?

Answer (score 9):

For browsers that support 3d transforms, e.g.: `-webkit-transform`, you could try the following:

```
your.div { -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,1px); }
```

Might not look like much, but doing the above causes the div in question to be hardware-accelerated.

Should you run into any flickering issues—they've been known to turn up in some cases—the following should sort you out:

```
your.div { 
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,1px); 
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

###### Via David Walsh - http://davidwalsh.name/translate3d

> The use of **translate3d** pushes CSS animations into hardware acceleration.  Even if you're looking to do a basic 2d translation, use `translate3d` for more power!  If your animation is still flickering after switching to the transform above, you can use a few little-known CSS properties to try to fix the problem

Hope that helps.

### 2023 addendum:

Vendor prefixes such as `-webkit-` and `-moz-` are no longer needed for most css3 properties including `transform` and `backface-visibility`. This has been true for quite some time. The [above] declaration could simply be:

```
your.div { 
    transform: translate3d(0,0,1px); 
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Bruh... Thank you sooooo much!

Answer (score 6):

As per my understanding, the issue and the solution drafted in the OP is two-fold:

- initially, within the match_height() function, the OP author retrieves the images that best fits the screen height, so that upon completed animation the user sees one full background image.
- after initial load, the user can navigate up and down the sections (with their respective background images) with the help of some buttons that trigger the scroll_to() function and its contained animation. Here is where the actual problem resides.

My efforts and the resulting fiddle focus on the scroll_to() function and the associated animation. I applied the following measures that, in conjunction, result in a (as per my subjective observation) '*smoother*' scolling experience:

- the original animation happened against 'html' *and* 'body', I'm reducing the jQuery selector to one selector only. In order to be able to use jQuery 1.9 (where jQuery.browser is deprecated) I'm using feature detection to get the 'right' selector:

  ```
  function getScrollerSelector() {
      var $body = $("<body/>");
      $body.scrollTop(1);
      return $body.scrollTop() == 1 ? "body" : "html";
  }
  ```
- In order to reduce the browser's processing load, I'm applying a logic that, per CSS, sets the background image of invisible sections to none during scrolling:

  ```
  .scrolldown.scrollto-a2 #a1,
  .scrolldown.scrollto-a3 #a1, .scrolldown.scrollto-a3 #a2,
  .scrolldown.scrollfrom-a3 #a4,
  .scrolldown.scrollfrom-a2 #a4, .scrolldown.scrollfrom-a2 #a3,
  .scrollup.scrollto-a3 #a4,
  .scrollup.scrollto-a2 #a4, .scrollup.scrollto-a2 #a3,
  .scrollup.scrollfrom-a2 #a1,
  .scrollup.scrollfrom-a3 #a1, .scrollup.scrollfrom-a3 #a2
      { background: none; }
  ```
- I played around with linear easing, but that did not necessarily improve anything

All in all, scrolling doesn't seem choppy to me any more, but please take into account that this is also dependent on the client computers processing power.

Here's the scroll_to() function:

```
function scroll_to(id, speed, margin) {
    var currentScrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
    var scrollTop = $('#' + id).offset().top - margin;
    var direction = scrollTop > currentScrollTop ? "down" : "up";
    $("body").addClass("scroll"+direction + " scrollto-"+id + " scrollfrom-"+getScrollFrom(direction));
    $( scrollerSelector ).animate({
             scrollTop: scrollTop
        }, {
             //easing: 'linear',
             duration: speed,
             complete: function() {
                 $("body").removeClass("scrollup scrolldown scrollto-a1 scrollto-a2 scrollto-a3 scrollto-a4 scrollfrom-a1 scrollfrom-a2 scrollfrom-a3 scrollfrom-a4");                     
             }
         }
     );
}
```

This is the [**link to jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/EHECD/15/)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are Scaling up the image, you can tell the Browser how to handle the rendering of image.
During the animation / scrolling, you can tell browser to Optimize on Speed and on completion of Animation / scrolling, Optimize on Quality.

Here is the CSS Property you can use on img: 'image-rendering' with values as optimizeSpeed / optimizeQuality.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/image-rendering

Comment: Only firefox & Opera as of now. Other browsers might catch this up fast. :)

Answer (score 0):

Testing locally it seems like your code should work ok, I have firefox 15 and chrome and don't see any lagging

What if you try this for the scroll to method?

```
function scroll_to(id, speed, margin) {
     $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $('#' + id)
     }, speed);
   }
```

Comment: Implementing the function results in an error "Expected token }"

Comment: lame, and with no :0? I updated my answer with some different code. I'm just not sure why it's really slow for you to scroll to a position. Maybe your computer can't handle it well?

Comment: Actually my computer does fine. But other people I've asked to test say it lags. It's really strange. Also - did you test with images that are at least 630 pixels in height and 1000 pixels in width? Because it does fine if there is a solid background color.

Comment: Ya I dropped in some big huge images off my camera. I'm not sure what the issue can be. Headed to bed, might think something up overnight

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do to images is smush it using http://www.smushit.com/ysmush.it/
this reduces the size of the image without loosing quality removing all unwanted meta data.

Comment: The problem here is probably more related to the actual image-data then meta-data since it's rendering and not loading that seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a website I was working on. In the end the problem seemed to be because of the large dimensions of the image that the computer/browser had to compute and render on screen.

My recommendation would be to try and reduce the amount of image that needs to be shown and scrolled on screen if possible.

Most modern browsers now support hardware (graphics card) rendering instead of the traditional (usually slower) software based (CPU) rendering. Hardware based rendering should in theory reduce that lag you're experiencing. However if your PC only has base or average graphics rendering capabilities, you're not going to have much success regardless. I personally had no success with either in Chrome, FireFox or IE until I gave in and removed the images.